# Install gcc 4.9 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, gcc, cuda, downgrade

I need to install gcc 4.9 on ubuntu 15.10 because a library I really need (caffe and its cuda dependancies) requires such version or lower.
I tried `apt-get install gcc4.9` but it isn't working. Is there any way I can make it?

Comment: *"it isn't working"* - what happens, exactly? FYI the package name is `gcc-4.9` (note the hyphen)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to correctly install gcc-4.9 is as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Comment: Doesn't the toolchain-r ppa typically only have *newer* versions than those in the standard repository? I only see gcc-5.2.1 there for Wily